# чем кроме сокетов и телнета можно прочитать данные игрового сервера?

Tags: python, сокет, udp

мне нужно послать upd запрос к серверу получить вывод данных (параметры сервера) 
за натом сокеты не работают, так что я постоянно получаю ошибку 10049.
как вариант я использоваю телнет, но он что-то долго работает, хотя может я им как то не так пользуюсь.

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "85.143.209.106"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST,26900)
print tn.read_all()
```

ищу наиболее быстрый способ получение этих параметров

вот пример на сокетах, он не работает. вылетает с ошибкой на бинде

```
from socket import *
UDP_IP = "acidstorm.bluefangsolutions.com"
UDP_PORT = 28000
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

sock.settimeout(10)
sock.recv(1024)

sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10049]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы не реализуете свой сетевой стек, то явно или не явно socket API используется для общения через сеть по UDP протоколу—оно реализовано на уровне системы в подавляющем большинстве случаев.

Telnet протокол здесь вообще неуместен. Он находится на уровне выше UDP и к тому же он реализован поверх TCP/IP протокола.

Ваша задача сводится к двум вопросам:

1. как правильно пользоваться socket API, чтобы данные по UDP протоколу посылать/прочитать:

   ```
   import socket

   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
   sock.sendto(b"data", (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
   ```

   Обратите внимание, нет SOCK_STREAM здесь, и нет явного `bind()`.
2. какие конкретно данные ожидает ваш игровой сервер—это зависит от сервера.

Comment: да я в принципе сокеты юзать не хочу. просто хочу сделать все как можно надежнее.

Comment: @JohnDoe ясно ли из моего ответа, что на практике для UDP (что подразумевает IP также) socket API придётся использовать явно или неявно? Если не можете или не хотите учить socket API, то попробуйте поискать специализированную библиотеку более высокого уровня, написанную для вашего игрового сервера (под капотом эта библиотека всё равно сокеты будет использовать).

Comment: так я разобрался как сделать, оказывается есть некий "протокол" общения с игровыми серверами Source Engine Query. Данные достал. но заодно нашел новую проблему, оказывается данные обычно читаются с query порта, а юзеру доступен только игровой порт. Вот теперь задача у меня как узнать query порт :/

Comment: вообщем оказывается есть valve master server, какой знает все существующие  сервера. ну и соответственно для него есть модули чтоб с ним работать и вытаскивать данные. так что зря я вообще с этими сокетами заморачивался

Answer (score 0):

За натом сокеты не работают? Вы о чем? Если вы подключаетесь к серверу со статическим внешним ip, то ваш сетевой `nat` тут вообще ни при чем. И любое соединение устанавливается сокетами, а `telnet` - всего-лишь протокол над `tcp`, так что вы что-то делаете не так с сокетами.

Вам стоит использовать `tcp` вместо `udp`, так как он гарантированно доставляет пакеты, и `bind` на клиенте делать не нужно.

Comment: дополнил пост примером на сокетах

Comment: Зачем делать `bind` сокета на клиенте? А еще, вы понимаете, как работает nat? По сути вам нужно соединяться с сервером по `tcp`, чтоб получить данные от него, а если вам так хочется сделать по `udp` (советую почитать про оба протокола), который **не устанавливает соединение**, то вам нужно сначала отправить что-то на сервер, чтоб он узнал адрес вашего клиента и на маршрутизаторе осталась запись для перенаправления за `nat` (про нат тоже прочитайте)